# Cutting a hole in a wall with displaced texture?

Tags: modifiers, displacement, 3d-printing

I don't know if this is possible.
I have added a displaced texture to a plane mesh to make a wall for 3d printing.
I have joined the two items together. I have tried the Boolean method to make a hole in the wall but the texture disappears. Is there a way of making a wall with a hole in it with added displaced texture?

[image: Top view]

[image: Side view]

[image: Cube added]

[image: Boolean applied result]

Comment: Sounds like the Boolean has disrupted the positioning (probably the UV mapping) of the displaced texture.  Hard to tell just from what you've posted, a screenshot of the shader tree and the plane's UV map might help.  Also, it can be a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem, and the image packed. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: @Eddy This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a printable solid mesh with modifiers only, here's how I would proceed:

1. First create whatever texture you want for your displacement (For the sake of simplicity I use here the texture *Stucci*).

   [image]
2. Then create a grid (with a relatively high resolution).

   [image]
3. Use the modifier `Solidify` and extrude the grid downwards. Additionally assign an identifier for *Shell* under *Output Vertex Group*. So that later you can displace only a certain part of the mesh.

   [image]
4. Apply the modifier `Displacement` with your previously created texture. Additionally use the Z-axis as *Direction*, and use the vertex group you created earlier with the Solidify-modifier.

   [image]
5. Finally use the modifier `Boolean` and cut whatever out of the mesh (in this example I just took a cube).

   [image]

[image]